# How to create a git post-receive hook which sends an email if a particular file has been modified?

Tags: git, email, version-control, git-post-receive

I want to add the following behaviour to a git repository, managed by gitolite. On something being pushed to master (can ignore other branches) I want to detect if a particular file has been changed in one of the commits, and if so, send an email to a specified address. The email contents can be the same every time. The email can be sent by executing a script or a bash command, assume the necessary executables are available.

How can this be done with git post-receive hooks?

---

Background: changes to a certain file requires an internal, manual process for something not controlled within the code. I want the email to be a reminder to complete that manual process.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved my goal by adding something like the following as a post-receive hook:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($from, $to, $branch) = split /\s+/, $i;
my ($project) = $pwd =~ /\/([^\/]+)\.git$/;
my $name_of_file_i_care_about = "SomeFileName.txt"

if ($project eq 'my_project') {

  my $contains_change_to_file_i_care_about = system( "git diff --name-only $from $to | grep --quiet $name_of_file_i_care_about" );

  if ($contains_change_to_file_i_care_about == 0) {
    system("mail --to 'someone\@somewhere.com' --subject 'Hey, that file you care about has changed.'");
  }
}

exit 0;
```

Note this depends on certain external commands: `grep` and `mail`. I have mostly copied and hacked up our existing post-receive hook, which may or may not depend on our specific configuration. If there is a better way, I'm all ears.

Comment: You can limit the diff to just the path(s) you care about with `git diff <flags> <oldrev> <newrev> -- <path> ...`.  In this case, just add the `-- $name_of_file_i_care_about` here and drop the pipe to grep.

Comment: Thanks @torek. IIRC the trade off is between a quicker `git diff` and being more robust to the file being moved, e.g. to a new directory. For me the extra bit of robustness is worth it.

Comment: If the file gets renamed, you enter a world of pain, because the next time someone pushes, it will slip by your script under its new name. You probably also want a check on whether the file still exists after the push, with a loud explosion if it doesn't.

Comment: @TomAnderson: good point. Do you know if it's possible to check for the presence of a file in a bare repository?

Comment: If you do a `git log --oneline $from..$to SomeFileName.txt`, that should print some number of lines if there have been changes, print nothing if there have been no changes, and fail (moan on stderr and exit with a nonzero status) if the file doesn't exist.